# Как получить текст из поля Input?

Tags: unity3d

Если можно по подробнее (смотрел тут ответы и ещё не понял).

На сцене есть объект инпут - PlayerNameInputField (создал ui->InputField).
У него есть вложенный объект (создается по умолчанию), отвечающий за текст (шрифт, размер, цвет)
Я его назвал PlayerNameInputFieldText.

Нужно по нажатию кнопки (на которой будет висеть скрипт с методом, проще говоря в методе), получить значение инпут поля.

Код ниже не работает

```
var gameObject = GameObject.Find("PlayerNameInputFieldText"); // Найдем объект.
var component = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>(); // Найдем его компонент (хоть так пиши, хоть PlayerNameInputFieldText)
Debug.Log("Текст в поле"+gameObject.Text);
```

[image: Картинка с input и текстом в нем]
PS

Знаю на среднем уровне C#/PHP/HTML/Delphi/CSS/JS.
Изучаю Unity вторую неделю. Испытываю некоторый шок, от невозможности использования стандартных приемов C# - инстанцирования (new), конструкторов которых нет у классов унаследованных от MonoBehaviour, инкапсуляции - когда открываем private поле SerializeField и т.д.

PPS

В интернете есть видео, где текст получают при изменении инпута - вешают отдельный скрипт на Update.
Не считаю нормальным выполнять код на каждый апдейт т.к. нам надо получить значение 1 раз.

Comment: "Код ниже не работает" --- в каком смысле? что выдаёт? ошибку или что-нибудь?

Comment: а если писать не `gameObject.Text`, а `component.Text` ? И, возможно, `component.text` (потому что оно именно с маленькой буквы https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html)

Comment: Добавил картинку.
Ошибка - Assets\Scenes\StartGameScene\SetData.cs(16,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Text' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Ругается на
var gameObject = GameObject.Find("PlayerNameInputFieldText"); 
var component = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>(); // Вот на эту строку - тут ошибка.

Comment: Страннно, что ты знаешь про C# и жаловался, что тут всё не так, как там, однако типичную ошибку не можешь понять.......ну не хватает нужного неймспейса, тебе откровенно говорят.......И нормальные IDE спокойно могут автоматом вставить их (видимо пора в блокнотах перестать разрабатывать)

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю ошибки и знаю английский язык.
Эти два скрипта находятся в одном неймспейсе - Player.

Пишу в VS Code. Потому что Mono Develop в Unity уже нет.
А Visual Studio 2019 некорректно работает с киррилическими путями.

Comment: Убрал неймспейсы - всё тоже самое.
Ошибка говорит об неверном типе ИЛИ неймспейсе Text - т.е. проще говоря система не понимает что это, просит объяснить, дать ссылку и т.д.

Comment: какие **два** скрипта? нет, ты не понимаешь текст ошибки, потому что он тебе пишет что для использования `Text`  надо его импортировать из неймспейса, в котором он объявлен. Т.е. нужный неймспейс для использования класса не подключен

Comment: Спасибо. Понял. Действительно забыл неймспейс using UnityEngine.UI;. Ошибка ушла.

Но всё равно не могу получить данные из инпут.
Я не знаю к какому компоненту обращаться (картинка).

Запустил сцену, посмотрел у какого объекта меняется текст при вводе.
Объект - PlayerNameInputField, компонент Input Field

По идее как то так
var playerNameInputField = GameObject.Find("PlayerNameInputField"); 
var text = playerNameInputField.GetComponent<Input Field>(); // Но тут синтаксическая ошибка.
И как обращаться к компонентам из 2х слов?

Comment: Заработало (забыл повесить скрипт на кнопку - метод не вызывался).
Но всё ещё непонятно, как обращаться к компонентам из 2х слов - React transform, Canvas renderer и т.д.

Comment: Почитать книги вполне может помочь ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Это обычные наименования классов, к которым ты так привык в C# и о котором упоминал пару раз, что там всё прозрачно. Это тот же C#, с некоторыми своими дополнениями и правилами. И у которых между словами в названии переменных и классов не может быть пробелов. Там обычный PascalCase

Comment: Не понял.  Вот так component = gameObject.GetComponent<React transform>(); обратиться не получиться - пишет синтаксическую ошибку т.к. мы параметризируем метод типом данных, состоящим из двух слов. Проще говоря - нельзя использовать в типе данных, переменной, имени класса, методе и т.д. 2 слова. CamelCase

Comment: Читайте книги, товарищ.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было добавить неймспейс и далее обратиться к объекту и компоненту и его свойству.

```
using UnityEngine.UI.
//.........
var playerNameInputFieldText = GameObject.Find("PlayerNameInputFieldText"); 
var text = playerNameInputFieldText.GetComponent<Text>();
player.Name=text.text;
```